# Double precision error in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, double

I am using openCV C++ libraries and calculated a double. It does the arithmetic but when I read out the number, prints out -1.#QNAN on the command prompt. What does that mean?
I am using a 64-bit i3 processor.

Comment: That usually means something's gone wrong. Debug the app and step through the arithmetic to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It means you got a quiet NAN, probably by dividing `-Inf / Inf` or multiplying something with `-Inf`, or perhaps casing a non-double into a double. It's not so much a precision error as much as it's an arithmetic exception.

EDIT: or adding/substracting `Inf` ...  read more on NaNs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, read more about floating point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)